# Bootstrap checkbox does not display in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, responsive

I have a responsive page built upon bootstrap. For some reason, I cannot get the checkbox to display in an iOS built device.  The checkboxes work in every browser imaginable, and even work in the developer module of chrome (emulating iOS devices) and even works in the iOS reader. It just will not display on an iPhone. Is it being hidden behind another element?

Thanks in advance!

http://www.johnstoncc.edu/FA/2/depnbrhhc.html

Answer (score 0):

Changing the column sizes to the following fixes it.

```
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-1" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <input id="OBKey_Signed_1" type="checkbox" name="OBKey_Signed_1" 
        value="Y" required="" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes" 
        style="-webkit-appearance: radio;">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-11">
        By checking this box, I ratify the use of my typed name and 
        Student ID number as an electronic representation of my signature.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for working so quickly on this.  And this worked well for the area at the bottom (The signature area) but I was unable to resolve the main area of content. 
Thanks again!